# extracting data from different part of a website in R

Tags: r

I need to have csv file of all streamflow data Hydrological Reference Station catchment in BOM(http://www.bom.gov.au/water/hrs/#panel=station-facts) site. but I'm not sure about the code. and there is error about access to site.. I know there is bomrang package also, but it doesn't install ... if you know about the issue, could you please help me...
I need to create a dataframe including all information for each Region, Basin and Station which you can see in the attached picture.
thanks in advance

```r
# Load required libraries
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

# URL of the website
base_url <- "http://www.bom.gov.au"

# Allowed directories
allowed_directories <- c("/act/", "/ant/", "/australia/", "/global/", 
                         "/nsw/", "/nt/", "/qld/", "/sa/", "/tas/", "/vic/")



**Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.**
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need to add/improve few bits to help others help you. Seems that a relevant block of code is missing, the current included code (just 2 object assignments) can't generate that error message. Referred picture also seems to missing. Perhaps explain the idea behind `allowed_directories` or is it just something from some other task and not directly related to this question? Aslo, what data exactly are trying to collect? Included link points to *Station Facts* tab, so all details from this tab?  Or CSV files from *Data Download* ?  Or Quick Facts section that's right from the map?